# Intellij adding extra line in new blocks

Tags: intellij-idea, code-formatting

When I'm writing code in Intellij, I often create new blocks by typing these types of sequences:

```
if (test) {
```

Typing that open curly brace causes Intellij to automatically insert a closing brace and move the cursor between the two braces:

```
if (test) {|}
```

At this point, I simply press Enter and get a nicely formatted block with the cursor right where it should be:

```
if (test) {
    |
}
```

However, today Intellij is adding an extra line to the block, like this:

```
if (test) {
    |

}
```

I've looked all over the project and IDE settings, but I'm not sure what to change. FYI, it's happening in various file types (.java, .js, .css) across different types of projects (Spring/Java, Node/Express). Anyone know how to fix this little annoyance?

Comment: Has somebody changed your ide settings?

Comment: Nope. I'm the only one who uses this computer.

Comment: In case this helps anyone else, I "fixed" the problem by going to Preferences > IDE Settings > Editor > Smart Keys and unchecking the "Insert pair bracket" box. I'm not sure why this stops Intellij from inserting an extra line at the end of new blocks, but it does. Unfortunately, the obvious side effect is that Intellij no longer automatically inserts closing parentheses or braces. Despite Engineer Dollery's last comment, I did _not_ change this (or any other) setting. What else could this be but an obscure bug in Intellij?

Comment: experiencing same issue. Just posted not knowing about this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28010094/intellij-idea-blank-lines-after-opening-brace-formatting?noredirect=1#comment44409663_28010094.

Comment: Try to disable Gauge plugin. Thanks Andrey Dernov from JetBrains Support for the advice to check custom plugins.

Comment: @KaPaHgaIII Thank you, that worked for me (and I have "Insert pair bracket" enabled again). If you add this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: What a relief. I can confirm that this has been introduced through the ``Gauge`` plugin in my setup and that uninstalling brought back the former behavior.

Comment: Hello, I'm experiencing the same issue on IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.1, except I'm coding JavaScript and JSON, and don't have any plugin named *Gauge*. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of 5MAR2015 the solution is to disable the Gauge plugin. Credit for this goes to @KaPaHgaIII

Comment: I use Android Studio (fresh install) and I'm seeing this. I don't have a Gauge plugin installed, so I can't disable it.

Comment: @colabug Try double checking your code formatting rules - the default whitespace insertion rules left a lot to be desired IMO

Comment: Yup, already did that. I've spent a lot of time staring at it since I'm setting up the code style settings for the team. Code Style -> Java -> Blank Lines: Have 0 in the all the areas related to classes. It only mentions Before '}' (not After '{'). Is there another place I should be looking?

Comment: @colabug at this point I'd say try disabling all your plugins and seeing if that helps. If not, maybe open a blank project and try there? I never found out exactly why this was happening, probably some sort of ill-conceived intellisense feature :-/

Comment: Yeah, this is a pretty vanilla Android Studio install. :-\

Answer (score 10):

Just got this error myself. Weirdly enough, for me it turned out to be the `AWS Toolkit` plugin.

If you have the same problem, it is most likely something with one of your other plugins if not the one mentioned above. I went through tons of IDE settings, and believe me, I wouldn't wish that upon anyone ;)

Comment: This started happening to me today with 2022.2.1. Disabling the `AWS Toolkit` plugin solved it for me. Thank you

Comment: Same thing here. Disabling `AWS Toolkit` plugin solved it equally! Thanks

Comment: OMG same here, I went thru all the settings hoping it's a new patch feature or something, ended up reinstalling everything and then after googling found out this answer... Turned out I have the same plugin enabled.

Comment: Disabling the AWS Toolkit solved it for me as well in both IntelliJ and WebStorm.

A fix appears to be on the way https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-jetbrains/pull/3278

Comment: This problem with AWS Toolkit has finally been fixed. https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-jetbrains/issues/3270

Answer (score 0):

I have neither the `AWS Toolkit` nor the `Gauge` plugins. The culprit was `Prettier`. Removing this plugin helped me lose the extra line between code blocks.