# Intellij IDEA Blank Lines after Opening Brace Formatting

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

For some reason I do not remember this as being default but trying to figure out how to make Intellij only insert 1 blank line instead of 2 blank lines after opening brace.

This is what my current default setup is doing:

````
```
myMethod(arg) {


}
```
````

But this seems more logical and what I want:

````
```
myMethod(arg) {

}

```
````

Comment: This seems to be happening to more people these days (ie. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27733987/intellij-adding-extra-line-in-new-blocks). Maybe it is some bug in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 2):

Go to:

<kbd>Editor</kbd> → <kbd>Code Style</kbd> → <kbd>Java</kbd> → <kbd>Blank Lines</kbd>

Choose how many spaces you want around methods, classes, etc...

Comment: thank you but even when I change number of blank lines to 1 or 0 within "Keep Maximum Blank Lines" -> "Before '}': it is still creating 2 blank lines after my opening brace instead of 1.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling Gauge plugin as recommended in this post did the trick: [Intellij adding extra line in new blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27733987/intellij-adding-extra-line-in-new-blocks).